# Unable to use Consumer<T> of java functional interfaces in android app API level 22

Tags: android, crash, android-api-levels

I am new to android development. I am targeting API level 22 and with the following code, the app crashes:

```
Consumer<String> onError = new Consumer<String>(){
    public void accept(String t){
    }
}
```

I tried with a custom class implementing this interface and still the same behavior. Can someone explain it why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Functional interfaces` like `java.util.Objects.Consumer` from **java8** cannot be accessed on devices targeted **java7** or lower. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) native support for `functional interfaces` is supported only from **API 24**